# Regex in SQL Server select like query with Unicode character properties

Tags: sql-server, regex, unicode-escapes

Is it possible to use Unicode character properties in a SQL select query with regex?

I would like to find tables in an existing database with names violating a set of rules. For example any table name which contains any of the :Sm Unicode characters (+, =, ~, |, <, and >). I have multiple groups in mind for the final query.

I imagine it could work something like:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%[:SM]%'
```

but it doesn't work, hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server has very limited regular expressions.  `LIKE` does not support character classes, in the sense of regular expressions.  You can list the valid characters themselves between the square braces:

```
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%[+=~|<>]%'
```